# Hiding submenuitems of jQuery UI Menu when parent is disabled

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using

```
$("#MenuItem1").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
$("#MainMenu").menu("refresh");
```

to disable a menu option conditionally before showing it.

This works perfectly fine, however I am still able to access the sub menu items of the #MenuItem1 is there a more standard way of disabling a menu item, I can't seem to find anything in the documentation (perhaps I am not asking the correct question)

Ideally if the item is disabled the submenu will not display, (I could disable all the submenu items, but id sooner not do this as I don't particularly want the user seeing the submenu items)

Desired effect is if MenuItemOne is disabled, SubMenuOnePoint1, SubMenuOnePoint2, SubMenuOnePoint3 will not be shown at all.

[Fiddle replicating what I have at the moment](http://jsfiddle.net/n76xo4xr/)

I am using jQuery UI - v1.11.1 and Jquery 1.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add class to that specific `li` instead of `a` tag:

add this:

```
$("#ui-id-3").addClass("ui-state-disabled")
```

instead of:

```
$("#MenuItem1").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/n76xo4xr/2/

Answer (score 1):

look jquery forum [answer](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/example-for-disabling-menu-item)

> I'd like to see a code example that demonstrates how to disable/enables a menu item when a certain event is fired.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n76xo4xr/8/ updated fiddle. seems to have desired effect, not particularly sure I like the inline event handlers, but it will do the trick at least until a better solution may be provided

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `ui-state-disabled` class on list item (`li`) elements, not the links. Here is revised fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/salman/n76xo4xr/4/ (use `.parent()` to get the li element)
- http://jsfiddle.net/salman/n76xo4xr/6/ (or add the id directly on the desired li)

Comment: upvote as Ehsan was first. parent() tip is useful though

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/n76xo4xr/1/

```
$("#TEST").menu();
$("#TEST").menu("disable");
```

instead of disabling the menu it hides it, if you want to use it. You need to call .menu() before you can call disable.

Comment: interesting idea, I wasn't even aware that the submenu was its own instance and could have methods called on it. It leaves behind the icon, but I don't think that would be too difficult to remove.